# Which method results in the highest probability of getting a Legendary Hero?

Tags: heroes-of-dragon-age

I have 3 Epic Heroes and 1 Legendary Hero, but I want more.  I have basically gotten every possible Rare hero and I don't care about getting them.  My question is, what is the best way to get Legendary Heroes?  The Recruit Pack, or the Soldier Pack?

The Recruit pack cost $350, and the Soldier costs $1500, so basically I can buy 29 Recruit Packs for the cost of the 7 Soldier packs.  If I just had the % chance of getting a Legendary Hero for each pack I could do the math, but I can't find that anywhere.  Does anyone know the percentages?

Answer (score 1):

I too have been recording my results for the soldier pack, I have opened 559 packs so far (over 800'000 coins worth), 490 were uncommon, 62 rare, 4 epic, 3 legendary. Do with these results as you will, they make percentages as follows.

Uncommon: 88% --------- 1 : 1.14

Rare: 11% ------------------ 1 : 8.98

Epic/Legendary ≈1% ----- 1 : 139 (Epic), 1 : 186 (Legendary)

To answer your Question though, I'm fairly sure it's the Soldier pack, my friend told me the recruit pack doesn't even have Legendaries, he has most of the legendaries. Also it would be logical, I mean what would be the point of the soldier pack if not for getting the better heroes. I don't think you'll get the actual percentages unless EA release them.

Comment: How do you know your totals?  Writing it down by hand?

Answer (score 1):

It is based on RNG really. If a random chance is involved, analysis result data will always vary from person to person. I might get a legend out of 1/1 or I might get nothing for months. The best we can do is to increase odds in our favor. If it is gold, collect 500k and then spam. If the gem is collected 750+, spam again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on this, i've been recording my outputs and my conclusion is that the odds are 1/7 for each level above the minimum for that pack. For example, the recruit pack has a 1/7 chance of getting uncommon or greater, 1/49 of getting rare or higher, 1/343 of getting epic or higher, 1/2401 to get a legendary. Although i've heard the recruit pack actually has no chance of getting legendary, the game lies.
Then for the Soldier pack it's 1/7 for rare, 1/49 for epic, 1/343 for legendary.
The Champion is 1/7 for epic and 1/49 for legendary.
Note that this trend has only been shown in my data for uncommon -> epic because I haven't got a single legendary yet :( and also i've actually only opened about 400 packs so these results could be off.

Comment: *edit* I've also heard that these odds are different for different people, which seems unlikely and unfair to me but my friends tell me that 1/7 seems too low for them and that theirs seems like 1/4.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is probably to by the sodier packs. Because the recruit ones have merely no chance of getting legendarys. If you have enough gems, I recommend you to get champion packs or the special packs. I have bought about 30-40 sodier packs and I've already got the architect.

Comment: I've bought probably 300 soldier packs, and have only gotten a single Legendary hero.  I've come to the conclusion that it's better to not waste gems on the champion packs, but use them in PVP matches that offer guaranteed heros.

Comment: I save my gems til I have enough for 2 10 packs of the special packs (thus guaranteed legendary). Takes time but better than relying just on luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have received at least 10 legendaries from the soldier packs, (over many many buys) but if you really want to get a decent one, save up your gems (maybe 120-150) max out a couple decent epics, and wait for a pvp event that suits your team. You will get epics. Or wait for a rare or uncommon pvp event. Try to get a team that has bonuses (they exist even for the low levels). Then use your gems to fight fight fight in the pvp event. You will NOT get top tier, don't even try, (it takes tones of gems) just use enough to get one or two legendaries. Make sure you are in your level bracket (that gives one or two you decide you want) the day the pvp ends, and just pay attention. Check it regularly, and make sure in the last 20 min or so you are paying close attention. You don't have to be at the front of that tier, just have enough to make it without losing. I just got two dragons from "Iron Bulls Dragon Hunt" pvp that way. Then with your epics, you will be able to do harder pve events which will drop more legendaries (I got two danariuses, and two caladrius on the previous week long pvp event). Good luck...it's a fun and addictive game!

Answer (score -1):

Ive heard that the odds are better at certain times of the day, but i also heard that the time that chances are higher switch everyday, for exampls chances were best a noon yesterday, and today theyre best at 3 pm, so because of this i have been doing it at the top of the hour rather than randomly like at 2:00 or 5:00 etc.never at 3:42 or 6:22 (those are just examples) hope this helps i know ive had decent results ive gotten 8 legendarys like this through the soldier pack and one from the recruit